# How do I use regex to find long lines and insert a newline at the last comma before a given column?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file open in Notepad++ in which some lines go past 112 columns, which I'd like to avoid.  By the time any of these lines gets to the 112th column, a comma has appeared in the string.  Like this.

`1,2,3,4...109,110,111,112,113`

(Let's suspend disbelief and imagine three-digit numbers take up one column each)

In the end I'd like something like this:

```
1,2,3,4...109,110,111,112,
113
```

So far I've figured out the regular expression to find all the lines that are too long:

`^.{113,}$`

For the life of me I can't figure how to capture the comma I'm looking for in the string up to that column so I can sub in a newline after it.

Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^(?=.{112})(.{0,111},)
```

It matches the begin of a line with at least 112 characters (by [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)), then matches as many characters as possible (up to 111) before a comma.

Replace this with with the captured group followed by a linebreak (`\1\n`).

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses to create a capture group:

```
^(.{112},).+
```

This will identify lines greater than 112 columns.  Then take the capture group, append a newline, and replace the capture group in the line.

Comment: Won't that only identify lines that exactly have a comma at column 113?

Comment: @Bergi I think that's the pattern that OP described, correct?  Each column is followed by a comma?  Or, did I miss something?